# Tensorflow tf.extract_image_patches for 3D images

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, 3d

Can someone provide an implementation for [tf.extract_image_patches](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/extract_image_patches) but that works with 3D images (ideally with n-dimensional tensors) I was thinking about using [tf.strided_slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice) but I can't figure out a way of using it without looping over the tensor...